# i want to delete last dot (.) from this version format 1.1.0010.1214.10

Tags: linux, shell

I tried with `sed` and `awk` but not getting in required format.

```
1.1.0010.1214.10
```

Expected output:

```
1.1.0010.121410
```

I tried below ways

```
echo "1.1.0010.1214.10" | sed -e "s/\(.*\)./\1/g"
1.1.0010.1214.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options

```
echo 1.1.0010.1214.10 | sed 's/\(.*\)\./\1/'
1.1.0010.121410

echo 1.1.0010.1214.10 | awk -F. '{ OFS=FS; print $1, $2, $3, $4 $5 }'
1.1.0010.121410
```

You were actually pretty close with your `sed`. All you missed was that `.` is a wildcard character for Regular Expressions, so in your case it matched the last character (`0`). To convert it into a literal dot you need to escape it as `\.`.

Comment: `... | rev | sed 's/\.//' | rev` :-)

Comment: @pLumo :-) I did consider adding that one

Comment: @roaima: thanks, i got my requirement.its working fine